# Problem with NXT tutorial

Tags: ros, nxt, tutorial, lego

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I'm trying to follow [this tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/nxt_ros/Tutorials/Creating%20a%20full%20robot) but when I launch the program I get this warning:

```
[INFO] [WallTime: 1335361633.048001] Creating ultrasonic with name 
  ultrasonic_sensor on PORT_2
[WARN] [WallTime: 1335361633.284565] caught an exception nxt.error.DirProtError
```

My yaml file has this characteristics:

```
- type: ultrasonic
  frame_id: r_ultrasonic_link
  name: ultrasonic_sensor
  port: PORT_2
  spread_angle: 0.2
  min_range: 0.01
  max_range: 2.5
  desired_frequency: 10.0
```

Supposedly, these lines creates an ultrasonic sensor with a spread angle of 0.2m, a min range of 0.01m, and a max range of 2.5m that is connected to PORT_2.

I only has this problem with the ultrasonic sensor. Touch and color (intensity) sensors work fine. I have the correct firmware (v1.28).

**EDIT**: I've listed the topics:

```
$ rostopic list
/intensity_sensor
/joint_command
/joint_state
/joint_states
/rosout
/rosout_agg
/touch_sensor
/ultrasonic_sensor
```

But when I try to see the topic I get this warning.

```
$ rostopic echo /ultrasonic_sensor
WARNING: topic [/ul/ultrasonic_sensor] does not appear to be published yet
```

Thanks in advantage for your help.

Cheers,

Raúl Pérula

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/32602/problem-with-nxt-tutorial/) by [raul.perula](https://answers.ros.org/users/1826/raul.perula/) on ROS Answers with karma: 71 on 2012-04-25

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I can't solve the warning, but seems like works.

---

Originally posted by [raul.perula](https://answers.ros.org/users/1826/raul.perula/) with karma: 71 on 2012-05-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0